# Another phrase for 'more that meets the eye'

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I was wondering if there is another phrase that has the same meaning as *'more than meets the eye'*? I have an assignment discussing picture books and my friend told me about this phrase, but I don't want to copy her. I say:

> 'Dust has many visual literacy elements, one page that is a good example of this is page seven..."

Comment: You need to mark 'Dust' as a title using italics or quotes, and replace the comma after 'elements' with something more heavy-duty  (I'd use a new sentence).

Answer (score 2):

The book has *hidden depths*.

From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/hidden_depths):

> **hidden depths** PHRASE
>
> Admirable but previously unnoticed qualities.
>
> ‘hidden depths and insights within children’

Answer (score 0):

**tuck away**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tuck)

> Hidden, either intentionally or incidentally by elements in the
>   surrounding area

As in:

> **Tucked away** in this book are ...